# How to fetch data and Trigger function from textbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input id = "textboxid" type="text" onkeyup="invoke();" />

<script>
function invoke() {
var enteredData = $('#textboxid').val();
alert(enteredData);
}
</script>
```

This is working fine but i want to do it without using onkey attribute and only jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#textboxid").keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });

});
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) jQuery event:

**HTML**

```
<input id = "textboxid" type="text" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#textboxid").on("keyup", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/juGyc/

```
$(function() {
  $("#textboxid").on("keyup", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this demo [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzYND/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textboxid").keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

**[KeyUp](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** : Bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for on Change or Blur

```
     $("#textboxid").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
```

[blur Event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery's `.bind()` method. Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTextBox").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
  });
});
```

OR

You can also bind events using jquery `.On()` -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textboxid").on("change paste keyup", function() {
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Kba/)

OR

Also bind the `.change()` event-

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#textboxid").change(function() { 
      alert($(this).val());  
     }); 
  });
```